# Go cli cant find my tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

When i try to run my tests in golang i get the following error

```
testing: warning: no tests to run
```

I also tried to create a test project to see if it behaves the same in other projects these are my 2 files.

```
package test

func test() string {
    return "test"
}
```

And here is my test.

```
package test

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
 )

 func testTest(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, "test", test(), "String was not test")
 }
```

I tried running it with:

```
go test
go test -v
```

Also i tested the behaviour in git bash and the cmd.
Im using Windows 10 with Go 1.7.1.

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test functions must begin with `Test`. Try renaming your function to `TestTest`. That should fix it. Full info here: https://golang.org/pkg/testing